# What is the standard SQL way to rename a column?

Tags: alter-table, sql-standard, rename

So far I've seen `ALTER TABLE RENAME`, `ALTER TABLE CHANGE` and `ALTER TABLE MODIFY`.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like `ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME col_old_name TO col_new_name`, which can be a case of modifying a column.

[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) goes with `RENAME`.
[MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/) and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) have all three.
[Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-alter.html#id-1.5.4.8.11) goes with `RENAME`.
[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#i2103924) has `RENAME` and `MODIFY`.
Standards are unkown to [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-columns-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

What is the database-agnostic way for renaming (or generally altering) a column?

Maybe I'm erroneously expecting the standard to cover DDL operations as well? I have code that works with multiple databases so would rather make the SQL part as portable as possible.

Comment: You're erroneously expecting that *any* DBMS actually fully supports the standard. *None* of them fully support it, and it's basically a waste of time trying to look for DBMS-agnostic code, just code to whichever product you are using. SQL Server uses `sp_rename`

Comment: I'm maintaining software that is using two products and would rather code agnostically but, alas, the world is nor perfect. I'll keep `#ifdef`ing as usual.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the standard is:

```
ALTER TABLE org ALTER COLUMN deptnumb TO deptnum;
```

When I doubt, I usually go to [SQL-Validator](https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/). I tried the latest of all DBMS at [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=f016e41d12de0c8a898fb7c9ab0d106c) and as far as I can tell Firebird 3.0 was the only one accepting that syntax.

To add to your list DB2 (luw) uses:

```
ALTER TABLE org RENAME COLUMN deptnumb TO deptnum
```

[DB2 documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=tables-renaming-columns)

FWIW, of the DBMS available at db<>fiddle:

- DB2 Developer-C 11.1
- MariaDB 10.6
- MySQL 8.0
- Oracle 21c
- Postgres 14
- SQLite 3.27
- YugabyteDB 2.8

Accepts the syntax `ALTER TABLE org RENAME COLUMN deptnumb TO deptnum`

Whereas:

- Firebird 3.0
- SQL Server 2019

Does not accept it.

Comment: The standard (at least the draft of the 2011 version I have) does not have a RENAME column command. The `<alter column definition>` command (ALTER TABLE .. ALTER COLUMN ...`) does not have any rename option.

Comment: I could not find rename either in the draft document. AFAIK this should be the standard `ALTER TABLE org ALTER COLUMN deptnumb TO deptnum` but very few DBMS seems to implement that.

Comment: Why do you think this should be the standard? I don't object but we usually don't get to decide ;)

Comment: I vaguely remember seen it before so I checked with `https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/`

Comment: Also, the fiddle for Firebird 3.0 did rename the column

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ ISO/IEC 9075-1:1999 seems to say the same, there is no such command.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ answer it 